# .bat - ping list of IPs and reply with response time only

Tags: batch-file, exe, ping

I'm stuck on this one, I've managed to create a batch file that imports list of IPs & hostnames but when I test for success or failure, I'd like to output how long it took. I don't know how to capture this and include it in the output. I'm trying to hide the default ping.exe output. Here's my code

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in (computers.txt) do (
   rem ping -n 1 %%A | findstr /i "TTL=" | find "Reply" > nul
   if %errorlevel% == 0 ( 
   echo %%B %%A successful ping in ?? Seconds
   echo %%B %%A successful ping [%date%, %time%] >> log.txt
   )
)
Pause
```

Comment: Multi-line for loop bodies and nested code blocks are so hard to get right, they aren't even worth looking at, much less writing them.  Better to convert them to subroutine calls.  Since you need the error level from each step, you'll have to break out that pipeline into distinct steps, storing intermediate results to a file or environment variable.

Comment: Please review [MCVE].  What data is stored in computers.txt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get batch script to display IP address, Ping status, and hostname into a single 3 column .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525308/unable-to-get-batch-script-to-display-ip-address-ping-status-and-hostname-into)

Comment: First, replace `if %errorlevel% == 0` by `if not errorlevel 1` which works also within a command block without usage of delayed expansion and checks if exit of `find` is not greater or equal 1 which means if `find` exited with return code 0 for success on finding the searched string. See Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576). Second you have to enable [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and reference `DATE` and `TIME` with exclamation marks instead of percent signs.

Comment: Further I suggest opening a command prompt window, run the following commands one after the other and read the help output on each command execution carefully from top to bottom: `for /?`, `ping /?`, `findstr /?`, `find /?`, `if /?`, `set /?`.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in (computers.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=7 delims== " %%G in ('ping -n 1 %%A') do (
        ping -n 1 %%A >nul

        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo %%B %%A unsuccessful ping
            echo %%B %%A unsuccessful ping [!date!, !time!] >> log.txt
        ) else if "%%~G" NEQ "of" if "%%~G" NEQ "0" (
            set ms=%%~G
            set ms=!ms:ms=!
            for /f %%Z in ('powershell !ms!/1000') do set second=%%~Z
            echo %%B %%A successful ping in !second! seconds
            echo %%B %%A successful ping [!date!, !time!] >> log.txt
        )
    )
)
Pause
```

Using `FOR /F`, it is possible to process command output.

- As you may see, I have 2 `ping -n 1 %%A`. It is because `FOR /F` doesn't capture the ERRORLEVEL generated by the processing command. The first command gets the output, the second gets ERRORLEVEL.
- `if "%%~G" NEQ "of" if "%%~G" NEQ "0"` filters out the unneeded results.
- The `powershell` command converts milliseconds to second(batch file does not support decimal numbers)

---

### I/O example

I don't have any other computers on my network, therefore I tested it with URLs.

```
Input                -> Output
www.google.com A     A www.google.com successful ping in 0.002 seconds
www.yahoo.com B      B www.yahoo.com successful ping in 0.032 seconds
a.a.a C              C a.a.a unsuccessful ping
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will try this out Asap