# Including first reply ping result in output file

Tags: cmd, ping

I've searched already and honestly, the responses I've found so far, I don't understand enough to modify my existing code.  Would appreciate any help.

I have a list of hostnames in a file called devices.txt and was provided this:

```
    :TOP    

    for /f %%j in (devices.txt) do call CS.CMD %%j

    :End
```

I then run the cs.cmd script I was provided which pings against the hostnames in the devices.txt file. Output is provided in 2 response files: Device_offline.txt
Devices_online.txt

The response files currently only contain the hostnames.  I would like to have the IP addresses as well (for the devices responding), and ideally as a single line of text per devices (that way I can separate in spreadsheet if needed)

Here is the current script:

```
    echo off

    :TOP    
    echo %1 - Processed Device
    echo.
    echo Seeing if system is on.
    echo.

    :test
    ping %1 -n 2 > pingout.lis
    find "bytes="<pingout.lis
    if errorlevel 1 goto badping

    :goodping
    echo.
    echo Checking status on %1
    echo 
    echo %1 - Device is online
    echo %1     >> Device_Online.txt
    goto End

    :badping
    echo
    echo %1 - No ping response...The Device is turned off.
    echo %1     >> Device_Offline.txt
    GOTO End

    :End
```

Conversely, I also have a list of IPs that I would like to ping and have offline/online output files with the associated hostname... maybe that's as easy as inputting IP addresses in the device.txt file instead of hostnames?

Appreciate any guidance, thank you!

Comment: Please try code snippet from [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30853474/3439404)

Comment: I tried the snipped by itself, changing the file patch to point to my .txt file.  CMD window flashes and disappears. I also tried inserting it within the first portion of my existing script and same thing.  Can you provide guidance on  how I can incorporate this snippet?  thank you!

Comment: Please do not try to _incorporate_ extraneous code snippets before _double checking_ their functionality. Please check the [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30853474/3439404)