# Batch file runfrom current folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If i want  run this script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set OUTPUT_FILE=results.txt
>nul copy nul %OUTPUT_FILE%
for /f %%i in (servers.txt) do (
    set SERVER_ADDRESS=ADDRESS N/A
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%x in ('ping -n 1 %%i ^&^& echo SERVER_IS_UP') do (
        if %%x==Pinging set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%y
        if %%x==Reply set SERVER_ADDRESS=%%z
        if %%x==SERVER_IS_UP (set SERVER_STATE=UP) else (set SERVER_STATE=DOWN)
    )
    echo %%i [!SERVER_ADDRESS::=!] is !SERVER_STATE!
    echo %%i [!SERVER_ADDRESS::=!] is !SERVER_STATE! >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
)
```

From folder

> C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Рабочий стол\

then cmd.exe is opening and inside i saw each line posting of code to cmd.exe and bat not work. or cmd.exe run and going black and script looping infinity times while cmd.exe is being closed.

If i put this script to c:\ and run it it work as requeried.

How to run bat file normaly from desktop?

Comment: I hope that your batch-file **is not entitled as `ping.bat`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this code snippet for analysing `ping.exe` output for IPv4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30853474/3439404) (saved and run below as `42046325_30852528.bat`). Running it shows that the original script (saved and run below as `42046325old.bat`) might return a totally false result e.g. for `192.168.1.12` IPv4 address `Destination host unreachable`.

Both script give the same results regardless if run

- by *double click* from file explorer, or
- by typing path to them from an open `cmd` window.

Note [`chcp` command](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) in `cmd`: I need to change active console [Code Page to `1251` (Russian)](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx)  or to `65001` (UTF-8) as my default system locale is `1250`.

**Output**:

```
d:\bat> chcp 1251
Active code page: 1251

d:\bat> "D:\bat\SO\Рабочий стол\42046325_30852528.bat" b
       hostname OP IPv4_address    explanation
       -------- -- ------------    -----------
        foo.bar ## foo.bar         Ping request could not find host
     google.com == 216.58.201.110  Reply from 216.58.201.110: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=55
  www.seznam.cz == 77.75.79.53     Reply from 77.75.79.53: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=247
    192.168.1.1 == 192.168.1.1     Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
   192.168.1.12 ?= 192.168.1.12    Reply from 192.168.1.100: Destination host unreachable.
        bmw.com =? 160.46.244.131  Pinging bmw.com [160.46.244.131]: Request timed out.
 origin.bmw.com =? 160.46.244.131  Pinging origin.bmw.com [160.46.244.131]: Request timed out.
Press any key to continue . . .

d:\bat> "D:\bat\SO\Рабочий стол\42046325old.bat"
foo.bar [ADDRESS N/A] is DOWN
google.com [216.58.201.110] is UP
77.75.79.53 [77.75.79.53] is UP
192.168.1.1 [192.168.1.1] is UP
192.168.1.12 [192.168.1.100] is UP
bmw.com [bmw.com] is DOWN
160.46.244.131 [160.46.244.131] is DOWN
Press any key to continue . . .

d:\bat>
```

BTW, analysing `ping.exe` output for [Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) would be completely different task.